# How to open the last modified file at startup?

Tags: command-line, startup, tab

As every user in this community understands, launching Vim using the command line without using any arguments or flags will edit a blank buffer with the `:intro` screen.

Some distributions and utilities support opening recent files in their main menu, *e.g.*, [LunarVim](https://www.lunarvim.org/). I have found no method for achieving the same result using Vim.

**Does Vi or VIM support this kind of feature using flags or options?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google exists.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic. Fortunately this one was easily removed. (« This plugin may solve your problem » is a fine answer, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the last file edited you can do:

```
vim -c "'0"
```

Or after starting Vim hit `'0`.

More information with [:help viminfo-file-marks](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#viminfo-file-marks)

But if you are interested by the MRU feature. There are two families of plugins that offers it:

- The Dashboards
- The Fuzzy Finders

### Browse OldFiles

Vim provide the command:

```
:browse oldfiles
```

It list you the files recently opened.

You can then:

- Scroll the list using the `j`, `k`, `d`, `u` keys,
- Quit the list using `q`

You are then prompted for a file index to open. If you are interested to the last opened file the index to select is `1`.

### Dashboards:

Here is a list of popular "Dashboards"

- [vim-Startify](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vim-startify)
- [Dashboard-nvim](https://github.com/nvimdev/dashboard-nvim) for Neovim only
- [Alpha-nvim](https://github.com/goolord/alpha-nvim) for Neovim only

Here the MRU list of the Startify dashboard:
[image: the Startify MRU list]

### Fuzzy Finders

Here is a list of some popular Fuzzy Finders together with their "MRU" commands:

- [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) and the `:History` command
- [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) and the `:CtrlPMRUFiles` command
- [vim-Clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap) and the `:Clap history` command (my favorite on Windows)
- [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) and the `:Telescope oldfiles` command for Neovim only

Here the Clap MRU popup:
[image: the Clap MRU popup]

Comment: Don't forget `:oldfiles`!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added to the list. I must admit that these long lists and the selection within the list via an index is not the most intuitive to me ;-)